# exporting lm summary results as a table in word for publication

Tags: r, export, lm

I have the below results. I would like to make clean publishable manuscript tables of these results in word but am unsure of the code which will allow me to do this via R and not through dreaded copy and paste. Can someone assist?

```
calfrg <- read.csv("~/Desktop/R/CalFRG2017.csv", header = TRUE)
attach(calfrg)
model1 = lm(formula = energy ~ infectionstatus+ fl + weight + site + infectionstatus*weight +site*weight + infectionstatus*fl + site*fl +weight*fl +infectionstatus*weight*fl + site*weight*fl, data = calfrg)
summary(model1)
model2 = lm(formula = percentmoisture ~ infectionstatus+ fl + weight +site + infectionstatus*weight +site*weight + infectionstatus*fl + site*fl +weight*fl +infectionstatus*weight*fl + site*weight*fl, data = calfrg)
summary(model2)
model3 = lm(formula = cf ~ infectionstatus + site, data = calfrg)
summary(model3)
model4 = lm(formula = relativecf ~ infectionstatus +site, data = calfrg)
summary(model4)
```

Comment: In addition to `knitr::kable`, mentioned in one of the answers, see the `kableExtra` package for increased flexibility in formatting of `kable` tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the output that goes to the screen using `capture.output` and then write it to a file.

```
SText = capture.output(summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ . , data=iris[,1:4])))
FileCon = file("IrisSummary.txt")
writeLines(SText, FileCon)
close(FileCon)
```

Comment: Or shorter is to use `file =` argument of `capture.output` to do this in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using knitr::kable() or pander::pander() and see. There're also other packages that help with this, the most powerful is probably tables but it does have a learning curve.   You can also assign the summary to an object and then process the object further to get the print the way you want it.